# SharePoint hosted app list

Tags: office-365

I am developing SharePoint hosted app.

WHere should I add my lists to ? Should I add them to app web ? would this happen automatically when I will add list to visual studio, it does creates a feature for me.

Would this feature going to be activated on app web automatically ?

Should i add my lists to host web ? and why ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you add list to VS, it will be automatically added in app web via the feature which will be activated by default.

Lists etc. added in app web are removed when you uninstall the app, so there is a chance of data loss. It depends on your requirement whether you want to use host web or app web. Please go through the below link for a good comparison between the two:

1. [SHAREPOINT APPS PLAYBOOK SERIES: PART 3 – HOST WEB VS APP WEB](http://www.jeremythake.com/2014/02/sharepoint-apps-playbook-series-part-3-host-web-vs-app-web/)
2. [Working with data in the app web, and why you should](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2012/09/sharepoint-apps-working-with-app-web.html)